# ASP.NET MVC 3: Can you create an ActionFilter that accesses request parameters BEFORE they are modified to fit an Action Method signature

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to add a bit of security/validation logging to an ASP.NET MVC 3 application I am working on.  What I would like to do is to decorate some of my Action Methods with an Action filter similar to this:

```
public class RegexValidateAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private static readonly ILog logger =
        LogManager.GetLogger( typeof( RegexValidateAttribute ).FullName );

    public string ParameterName { get; set; }
    public string Expression { get; set; }

    public override void OnActionExecuting( ActionExecutingContext filterContext )
    {
        string parameterValue = Convert.ToString(
            filterContext.ActionParameters[ ParameterName ] );
        if ( parameterValue != null )
        {
            if ( !Regex.IsMatch( parameterValue, Expression ) )
            {
                logger.Error( "INPUT_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION [ Parameter "
                              + ParameterName + " did not match the regex: '"
                              + parameterValue + "' :: '" + Expression + "']" );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My Controller is defined similar to this:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{        
    [RegexValidate( ParameterName = "id", Expression = @"^\d+$" )]
    public PartialViewResult MyMethod( int id = 0 )
    {
        <Action Proccessing>
    }
}
```

The "issue" that I am having is that because the input parameter to the action method is defined as an `int`, if someone passes in a non-numeric value the parameter value is changed to 0 during the process of determining which action method to select.  Of course, this occurs BEFORE my ActionFilter has a chance to execute, and therefore I do not get the chance to log the original invalid value.

I know that this can be solved by changing the parameter to be defined as a `string`, but that would require me to rework a lot of code, and to then add conversion logic to the action method to convert from a string to an int.

So, is there any way to get the original value in the ActionFilter instead of the modified value, or to have the ActionFilter execute before the value is modified?

Update:
Based on @Darin's suggestion below of using an AuthorizationFilter, I was able to accomplish my goal with code similar to the following:

```
public class RegexValidateAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    private static readonly ILog logger =
        LogManager.GetLogger( typeof( RegexValidateAttribute ).FullName );

    public string ParameterName { get; set; }
    public string Expression { get; set; }
    public string ReplacementValue { get; set; }

    public override void OnAuthorization( AuthorizationContext filterContext )
    {
        string parameterValue = Convert.ToString(
            filterContext.RouteData.Values[ ParameterName ] );
        if ( parameterValue != null )
        {
            if ( !Regex.IsMatch( parameterValue, Expression ) )
            {
                logger.Error( "INPUT_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION [ Parameter "
                               + ParameterName + " did not match the regex: '"
                               + parameterValue + "' :: '" + Expression + "']" );
                filterContext.RouteData.Values[ ParameterName ] = ReplacementValue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why don't you put that constraint on the route itself?

Comment: @MikeSW I am not sure what you mean by that.  Do you have an example you could share?

Comment: basic routing http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx#adding_constraints_to_routes . Although the code is for web forms, you'll find lots of similar examples for mvc just by googleing

Comment: @MikeSW I found out about Route Constraints, and while they do solve one issue, namely not matching non-numeric values, they do not give me the ability to log requests that are invalid, which I would like to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you derive from [ActionFilterAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionfilterattribute.aspx), the model binder runs **before** your `OnActionExecuting` method. And when the model binder runs it crashes. If you want your method to run before the model binder you should implement the [`IAuthorizationFilter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.iauthorizationfilter.aspx)
interface or derive from the [`AuthorizeAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.aspx) which already implements that interface.

Another possibility is to add constraints to your routes so that the controller action is not invoked if the id is not numeric:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    new { id = @"^\d+$" }
);
```